# Saving SentencepieceTokenizer in Keras model throws TypeError: Failed to convert elements of [None, None] to Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sentencepiece

I'm trying to save a Keras model which uses a `SentencepieceTokenizer`.

Everything is working so far but I am unable to save the Keras model.

After training the `sentencepiece` model, I am creating the Keras model, call it with some examples first and then try to save it like so:

```py
proto = tf.io.gfile.GFile(model_path, "rb").read()
model = Model(tokenizer=proto)
embed = model(examples)
assert embed.shape[0] == len(examples)
model.save("embed_model")
```

The model itself is straight foward and looks like this:

```py
class Model(keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, tokenizer: spm.SentencePieceProcessor, embed_size: int = 32, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tokenizer = tf_text.SentencepieceTokenizer(model=tokenizer, nbest_size=1)
        self.embeddings = layers.Embedding(input_dim=self.tokenizer.vocab_size(), output_dim=embed_size)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.tokenizer.tokenize(inputs)
        if isinstance(x, tf.RaggedTensor):
            x = x.to_tensor()

        x = self.embeddings(x)
        return x
```

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: Failed to convert elements of [None, None] to Tensor. 
Consider casting elements to a supported type. 
See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.
```

It appears to me as if the model literally gets called with `model([None, None])` after calling `model.save()`.

To be precise, the error appears to occur in `ragged_tensor.convert_to_tensor_or_ragged_tensor(input)`:

```
E                       TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model" (type Model).
E                       
E                       in user code:
E                       
E                           File "/home/sfalk/workspaces/technical-depth/ris-ml/tests/ris/ml/text/test_tokenizer.py", line 20, in call  *
E                               x = self.tokenizer.tokenize(inputs)
E                           File "/home/sfalk/miniconda3/envs/ris-ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_text/python/ops/sentencepiece_tokenizer.py", line 133, in tokenize  *
E                               input_tensor = ragged_tensor.convert_to_tensor_or_ragged_tensor(input)
E                       
E                           TypeError: Failed to convert elements of [None, None] to Tensor. Consider casting elements to a supported type. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes for supported TF dtypes.
E                       
E                       
E                       Call arguments received by layer "model" (type Model):
E                         • inputs=['None', 'None']
E                         • training=False
E                         • mask=None

/tmp/__autograph_generated_file99ftv9jw.py:22: TypeError
```

Comment: @AloneTogether Sorry, I forgot to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try defining an `input_signature` for the `call` method. Also call `self.tokenizer.vocab_size().numpy()` instead of `self.tokenizer.vocab_size()`, since eager tensors are not serializable:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text as tf_text
import requests

url = "https://github.com/tensorflow/text/blob/master/tensorflow_text/python/ops/test_data/test_oss_model.model?raw=true"
sp_model = requests.get(url).content

class Model(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, tokenizer, embed_size: int = 32, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tokenizer = tf_text.SentencepieceTokenizer(model=tokenizer, nbest_size=1)
        self.embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=self.tokenizer.vocab_size().numpy(), output_dim=embed_size)

    @tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec([None], tf.string), tf.TensorSpec([None], tf.int32)))
    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        x = self.tokenizer.tokenize(inputs)
        if isinstance(x, tf.RaggedTensor):
            x = x.to_tensor()
        x = self.embeddings(x)
        return x

model = Model(sp_model)
embed = model(["What you know you can't explain, but you feel it."], training=False, mask=[1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
model.save("embed_model")
```

Note that I removed the `training` parameter from the `call` method, since it already exits. Also, if you can set `self.built=True` in the constructor so you will not have to call your model on actual data but it is up to you:

```
class Model(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, tokenizer, embed_size: int = 32, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.tokenizer = tf_text.SentencepieceTokenizer(model=tokenizer, nbest_size=1)
        self.embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=self.tokenizer.vocab_size().numpy(), output_dim=embed_size)
        self.built = True

    @tf.function(input_signature=(tf.TensorSpec([None], tf.string), tf.TensorSpec([None], tf.int32)))
    def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
        ...
        return x

model = Model(sp_model)
model.save("embed_model")
```

Oh, and you might have to change the `input_signature` depending on which tokenizer model you are using.